# Django template access value within for loop in templatetag

Tags: django, django-templates

Long story short I'm curious if there is any way to pull the the value of an obj within a for loop to a custom template tag?

I currently have

```
{% for OBJ in OBJ_LIST %}
{% TAG 'string_value' OBJ %}
{% endfor %}
```

trick is I get 'OBJ'

which when run through either

```
obj = template.Variable(objname)
obj = template.resolve_variable(objname, context)
```

doesn't register the variable within a for loop

curious if there is any type of work around?

Comment: To clarify, if you pull this outside of the loop, it works?

Comment: yes, works just fine when there is a var declared in context -- it  just passes the name of the var so it would get the string 'modelInstance' vs ModelInstance -- figure a simple way to get around is to look the object pack up but trying to keep it DRY

Comment: Reviewed code after a few hours sleep and managed to get it working, tinkered with so much not sure where my specific issue was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, my tags works fine in loops. I think there an error somewhere in your template tag. But instead of debugging, I recommend using some existing framework to create template tags ([this](https://github.com/vbmendes/django-meio-easytags) or [this](https://github.com/ojii/django-classy-tags) or something else). It will be DRY, well-tested and you won't be able to make such errors.

Comment: the tag works perfectly outside of a for loop - though inside if it was a new var that wasn't declared in context nothing would show up -- that said the links you posted offer just what I was looking for -- thank you

Comment: @yugi part of me wants to upvote your comment just for using cool beans, but I agree as well.